# Request runtime permissions on android

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I am trying to get runtime permissions on my app. However the app is not displaying the dialog to request the specific permission. The code below only works when the GPS is turned on on the phone manually.
I am running the app on Android 5.0.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_location = findViewById(R.id.get_location);
    txt_latitude = findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    txt_longitude = findViewById(R.id.longitude);
    txt_timestamp = findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
    btn_map = findViewById(R.id.map);
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    btn_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getLocation();
        }
    });

}

private void getLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        }, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < Location > () {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    mLastLocation = location;
                    txt_latitude.setText(getString(R.string.location_latitude, mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
                    txt_longitude.setText(getString(R.string.location_longitude, mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
                    txt_timestamp.setText(getString(R.string.timestamp, mLastLocation.getTime()));
                } else {
                    txt_latitude.setText(R.string.no_latitude);
                    txt_longitude.setText(R.string.no_longitude);
                    txt_timestamp.setText(R.string.no_timestamp);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getLocation();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.location_permission_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you add these permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: Yes I have...I want it to display the dialog to prompt a user to allow the app to use the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are run on **Android 5.0** the Android runtime permission won't be shown. As runtime permission is only be shown starting from **Android** **6** (Marshmellow).

Please check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for the runtime permission details.